# Playing an audio or video file right after it is downloaded

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I use `NSURLConnection` delegate methods to download either a video or audio file, the download is OK, now i need to play it right after it has finished downloading.

My relevant code is this:

```
 -(IBAction)downloadAndPlay:(id)sender{
    NSString *fileUrlPath=[host stringByAppendingString:rowContent];  


            // Create the request.
            NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileUrlPath]
            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
            timeoutInterval:60.0];


            // create the connection with the request
            // and start loading the data
            NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

            if (theConnection) {
                // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.

                receivedData = [NSMutableData data] ;
                //NSLog(@"connection succeeded");

            } else {

                // Inform the user that the connection failed.
                UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Music Album" message:@"Connection failed, please try again" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alertView show];

            }
    }

  //NSURLConnection delegate methods  
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
    {
        // This method is called when the server has determined that it
        // has enough information to create the NSURLResponse.

        // It can be called multiple times, for example in the case of a
        // redirect, so each time we reset the data.

        // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
        [receivedData setLength:0];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
    {
        // Append the new data to receivedData.
        // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
        [receivedData appendData:data];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
      didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
    {

        // inform the user
        NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
              [error localizedDescription],
              [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
    }

    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
        // do something with the data
        // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
        NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);

    }
```

How can i play the file (either audio or video) right after it is downloaded (auto play).
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: How can i play the file right after it is downloaded :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to save the data you've downloaded to a file, and then open the file using a `MPMoviePlayerViewController` or similar. Right now you just download your file as `NSData`, and leave it at that.

So save your `NSData` object to the file system with the appropriate name/extension (or just write your download to the file system itself, which makes more sense for larger files), get a file URL handle, and pass it to your media player.

Comment: If one is going to download and save to a file, one should use `NSURLDownload` instead of `NSURLConnection`.